# IntelliJ is giving cannot resolve compiler issue

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting "Cannot resolve symbol" for almost all classes in my intelliJ.
But when i build it, build gets successfull.
Only the compiler will show these errors.

I have tried following things:
deleted .idea folder, deleted build folder
, Invalidated caches and Restart,
Reimport Gradle project.

When I check the Gradle properties, it is pointing to the right JDK(OpenJDK 14)

and this issue is intermittent, not exactly sure whats causing this issue.

let me know if I am missing something here.

below is my compiler settings
[image]

All that i see is unresolved classes.
[image]

and Project JDK is correct and my Project is referring to same JDK.
[image]

Comment: check jdk setting in project properties

Comment: yes it is pointing to the right JDK

Comment: can you expand imports block and check if the packages you importing are included in project and if you are using modules - if proper modules dependencies are set?

Comment: yes, they are from the same module.

Comment: try refreshing dependencies as per my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

check jdk setting in project structure as per picture below, or from main menu **file -> project structure -> platform settings -> sdks**, this is a typical error when project SDK is not set[image]

also, run graddle refresh dependencies(3) and refresh dependecies in intellyJ(4):
[image]

Comment: Hi @GiorgosDev, the problem is solved by upgrading gradle and by disable/enabling the gradle plugin. 
Thanks for helping.